# Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.- java spring project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am new to java. Created a sample spring project and trying to connect to the local mysql database.
Below is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.org</groupId>
    <artifactId>dbtest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>dbtest</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Application.properties file is as below:

```
jdbc.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/HR
jdbc.username = HR
jdbc.password = admin
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect.class
server.port = 3080
```

I am still not able to connect to the mysql db. however i could access the db from mysql workbench.

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter naming is invalid. Please use
spring.datasource named parameters, something like this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/HR
spring.datasource.username=HR
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect.class
```